# verb form: require or requiring?

Tags: verbs, gerunds

An Australian colleague of mine wrote the following sentence:

> How many toilets requiring maintenance is difficult to foresee.

I'd like to know whether the verbal **requiring** is in the correct form in the sentence as it is presented here (btw, it's only one of the four options for a multiple choice question). Should it be **require**?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Was "will require" one of the options on this test?

Comment: No, the sentence itself is an option, along with other sentences.

Comment: "Require" is correct though "will require" might be preferable. That aside, the expression "How many toilets require maintenance" is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question), where the meaning is "The answer to the question 'How many toilets require maintenance?' is difficult to foresee". Note that the extraposed version is also possible: "It is difficult to foresee how many toilets require maintenance".

Answer (score 1):

You cannot *foresee* something which exists in the present.

> It is difficult to predict how many people eat tuna. <sup>sorry, Charlie</sup>

It is difficult to say, to know, to tell, to estimate, to measure ...

> It is difficult to say how many toilets require maintenance.
>
> It is difficult to say how many toilets requiring maintenance there
>   are.
>
> It is difficult to say how many toilets there are requiring maintenance.
>
> How many toilets require maintenance is difficult to say.
>
> How many toilets requiring maintenance there are is difficult to say.
>
> How many toilets there are requiring maintenance  is difficult to say.